# Using AWS Lambda to trigger EMR step to bulk load data to Hbase cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, hbase, workflow, etl, amazon-emr

I'm looking to write an ETL solution that orchestrates copying data from S3 into an AWS EMR cluster running Apache Hbase.

The steps I'm looking to write are as follows:

1. CSV file is uploaded to S3 bucket.
2. Lambda function is triggered, moving the file from S3 into the Hbase cluster's HDFS
3. Invoke Hbase's [ImportTsv](https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#importtsv) utility to bulk load the CSV on HDFS into an Hbase table.

I'm new to the world of AWS, so I'm not sure what the best tools are to orchestrate this workflow. How would I go about implementing this?

Comment: Submit a step job when lambda is triggered. The step can do the downloading data from s3 and run emr command to bulk load csv into hbase.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Is this the best way to go about getting data into Hbase from S3? Or is there a more efficient method?